# Checking each field of a FORM must not be EMPTY via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Unfamiliar with jQuery...

How can check each **Input field** of a FORM that must not be EMPTY after user clicking on Submit button via jQuery? Submission of FORM is only permitted after each field is checked and it must not EMPTY even though "Submit button" is being clicked upon! All fields must be entered accordingly, then Submit even is only permitted through...

NOTE: The Form, which consists of 10 Input Fields, is coded in HTML only; I need jQuery to check each Input Field that must not be EMPTY...

Thank You those who are willing to offer me your helping hands....

Comment: Show your html and js for better suggesstion

Comment: Use JQ validation for that. The JQ validation check on value change and after click on the submit button.

Comment: Also, you can add `required` attribute in form input.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this [validator plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) of jQuery. There you can set your validation rules and messages.

Comment: Thanks for thingEvery & Sajeeb Ahamed!! Ahamed, your ideas could be feasible; but it's hard for me! Just attempted to validate a single filed; it triggers to validate all other fields as "required" flag in all INPUT fields. Sound great; but it refreshes to the Top Page without sending successfully. It does prompt me this Message: ["The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?"] Clicked on both "Continue" or "Cancel" buttons repeatedly stuck on prompting same Message.

Comment: Do you need to display any message for individual input if it is not filled?

Comment: Sajeeb Ahamed , Thanks again!  Nope! When I activate checking ONLY in any SINGLE field manually, it validates & prompts out Message (This field need to Fill) AUTOMATICALLY  without my efforts in any fields that have the FLAG ("Required") coded in all INPUT field. After filling up all necessary INPUT fields, it refreshes to  very TOP Page without sending at all. When I refresh manually, it prompts this funny message ["The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?"]. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, Gentlemen for your excellent help!.

Comment: Thanks, Gentlemen for your excellent help!. After numerous attempting failures, I did validations in a different approach. Instead of validating  occur during the SUBMIT Event, I did it by intercepting each Input field $("#name").focusout(function(){...} " Event enclosed in the $("contact-form").focusin(function() {...}. It works magnificently. In fact, the right way, it should be un the SUBMIT  Event; thus, it failed to submit accordingly

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery needed.

[HTML attribute: required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

> The Boolean required attribute which, if present, indicates that the
>   user must specify a value for the input before the owning form can be
>   submitted. The required attribute is supported by  text, search, url,
>   tel, email, password, date, month, week, time, datetime-local, number,
>   checkbox, radio, file,  types along with the  and
>    form control elements. If present on any of these input
>   types and elements, the :required pseudo class will match. If the
>   attribute is not included, the :optional pseudo class will match.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
```

Comment: Yes! I did use "required" as shown with Placeholder class to alert/ advise... Once the Submit button is being clicked; it still proceed through with EMPTY fields....